# How to keep one thread to call multiple JForms?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, runnable

Let's say I have one thread running (I'm creating many instances of this thread), and inside that I instantiate a `JForm`. While being inside that `JForm`, I call another `JForm`. Think of it as a multiple step registration process. When I'm inside the second form, will the previously created thread still be inside the `run()`? Or is the new `JForm` creating a new thread? I want to keep the first thread alive and access a shared resource through out the lifetime of it.

```
class Form1 extends JForm{
   public void jButton1ActionPerformed(..){
      ///show Form2
   }
}
class A extends Thread{
  public void run() {
     //show Form1
  }
}

class Main {
 public static void main(String args[]){
    new A().start();
    new A().start();
    new A().start();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How can you create "many instances" of a thread? Please clarify.  Also, all Swing code is created on one single thread, the EDT, so your question and description is very confusing.

Comment: inside Main class: new A().start(); new A().start(); ...

Comment: OK, but even so, all Swing code must be called on one thread, the EDT, usually by queuing a Runnable onto the event thread via SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...).

Comment: Again, you need to clarify what you are trying to do. What do you mean "access a shared resource..."? If a variable, then this has nothing to do with a thread being alive or dead. If not a variable, then what?

Comment: I'll have a look at EDT stuff. Each A object (active entity aka Thread) will have to use methods in a Mutex/Shared Resource (passive entity) while it's alive. So the Shared resource will have synchronized methods for mutual exclusion. wait(), notify(), notifyAll() will be included in the Mutex to control threads (A objects) trying to acquire it's lock and call methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create and run your A thread, you will simply show the Form and continue executing that Thread.  Separately, on the single, dedicated Swing Thread (started automatically for you) the users click will be caught and handled, resulting in a call to `jButton1ActionPerformed`.  That code block will execute inside the Swing thread.

Hope that helps.  Note that you can name your threads and always use `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to help you understand further what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create and show a Swing component from within a non-EDT thread, you must place the Swing code in a Runnable and queue it on the event thread like so:

```
class A extends Thread{
   public void run() {
      //show Form1
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
 }
```

So regardless of how many "A" objects you create, and thus separate new threads you create, all Swing code will be running on the same one thread.

Comment: I've commented above about my Shared resource setup. pls have a look. thanks